# Unable to view data in docker volume using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to use docker volume for the first time and I am having a hard time getting the container to share files with the host machine (Ubuntu). I can see the files my code is writing inside the container using docker exec but none of the files are in the volume under /var/lib/docker/volumes.

My DockerFile

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN apk add dumb-init
RUN addgroup gp && adduser -S appuser -G gp

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/logs

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN chown -R appuser:gp /usr/src/app/logs/

USER appuser
```

My docker-compole.yml

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  my-service:
    user: appuser
    container_name: demou 
    build:
      context: . 
    image: "myService" 
   
    working_dir: /usr/src/app 

    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # 
    environment:
      - NODE_VERSION=16 
    volumes:
       - /logs:/logs/:rw
    command: sh -c "dumb-init node src/server.js"
    networks:
      - Snet
  # restart: always
volumes:
  logs:
   # driver: local
    name: "logs"
networks:
  Snet:
    name: "Snetwork"
```

server.js doesn't do anything besides writing a helloworld.txt file to the logs directory. when I run the app in the container,I dont see any errors or even warning. It's just the logs are not available on the host machine where docker keeps its volumes.  What I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The compose file uses a bind mount (indicated by the leading `/` before `logs`:

```
...
services:
  my-service:
    ...
    volumes:
       - /logs:/logs/:rw
       # ^ this slash makes the mount a bind mount
    ...
```

We actually want to use a named volume by removing the leading `/`:

```
...
services:
  my-service:
    ...
    volumes:
       - logs:/logs/:rw 
       # ^ no slash, will be interpreted as named volume
       #   referencing the named volume "logs" defined below
    ...
volumes:
  logs:
   # driver: local
    name: "logs"
...
```

For more details, please refer to the [relevant `docker-compose` file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

---

As an aside: I had problems starting the `docker-compose.yml` file due to an invalid reference format. The image name must not include uppercase letters. So I had to change it to `my-service`. Even then, I was not able to build the `my-service` image due to missing files.

Here is a full `docker-compose.yml` that reproduces the desired behaviour, I used an alpine with a simple script to write to the volume:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  my-service:
    image: alpine:3.14.3
    working_dir: /logs
    volumes:
       - logs:/logs/:rw
    command: sh -c 'echo "Hello from alpine" > log.txt'
volumes:
  logs:
    name: logs
```

Comment: Sorry about the image name, I forgot about the caps issue.
The issue is still there. I can see the log directory when I run under docker volume ls but the _data directory is always empty.

Comment: Which version of docker-compose are you using? I am using the latest one but I wouldn't mind downgrading to an older one

Comment: `Docker Compose version v2.0.0`

Comment: Sorry, I got the error using my image but the error is gone when I used the alpine image as per your example. The question is why isnt my image behaving the same way?

Comment: That seems to be a permissions problem. Can you: stop all containers. delete the volume `logs`, and re-run `docker compose up`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the previous comment. using the alpine image works but not my image

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: If I had to guess, I would assume it is because in the containerfile, we set the active user to `appuser`. This user most probably does not have permissions to write to `/logs`. Try adding `RUN chmod -R 777 /logs` or `RUN chown -R appuser:gp /logs` before `USER appuser`.

Comment: I suspected the same original and setup the permission using what you proposed but then run `docker-compose up --build`, check docker volume under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/logs/_data` and it was empty even though the app in the container written two files to its /log directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239194/discussion-between-turing85-and-dev9).

Comment: Thanks again @turing85. the problem was with the way I mounted the directory but your solution to use ` - logs:/app/logs/:rw` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You hint that you're trying to actually read the logs that come out, reasonably enough.  For this use case you should use a Docker bind mount and not a named volume.

Where you specify

```yaml
volumes:
  - /logs:/logs:rw
```

The first part (starting with a slash) is an absolute path on the host; if you `ls /` on the host system, outside a container, you should see the `logs` directory there.  The second part is a path inside the container, which doesn't match what you've indicated in the Dockerfile.  If you change it to

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./logs:/usr/src/app/logs:rw
  # ^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

making it a relative path on the host side and the intended directory on the container side, then you will be able to directly read the logs in a subdirectory of the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file.  You can delete the `volumes:` block at the end of the file.

(For completeness, if the left-hand side of a `volumes:` entry doesn't contain a slash at all, it refers to a named volume specified in the top-level `volumes:` block; see also [@Turing85's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69959201).)

Permissions-wise, the container process must run as the same *numeric* user ID that owns the log directory.  Any other directories that the container *writes* to must also have the same *numeric* owner.  It doesn't matter if the code in the image is owned by root (in fact, it's better, because it prevents the code from being accidentally overwritten).

```yaml
user: 1000  # matches host uid; try running `id -u`
volumes:    # or `ls -lnd logs`
  - ./logs:/usr/src/app/logs
```

Also consider setting your application to log to stdout, instead of a file.  That avoids this problem, and you can use `docker logs` to read the log output.  In more involved container environments like Kubernetes, there are standard ways to collect logs-to-stdout from containers, but it's much trickier to collect logs-to-files.